# Is there any way to get rid of the error?

Tags: python, input

I started coding in python 2 days back.In hackerrank I was solving the problems and I am unable to find the error in this code.
Here is the problem.

A left rotation operation on an array shifts each of the array's elements  unit to the left. For example, if  left rotations are performed on array , then the array would become .

Given an array  of  integers and a number, , perform  left rotations on the array. Return the updated array to be printed as a single line of space-separated integers.

Function Description

Complete the function rotLeft in the editor below. It should return the resulting array of integers.

rotLeft has the following parameter(s):

An array of integers .
An integer , the number of rotations.

Input Format

The first line contains two space-separated integers  and , the size of  and the number of left rotations you must perform. 
The second line contains  space-separated integers .

Output Format

Print a single line of  space-separated integers denoting the final state of the array after performing  left rotations.

## here is my code

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

n , d = input().split()
a = d % n
b = n - a
l = []
while(n>0):
    k = input().split()
    l.append(k)
    n=n-1
while(b>0):
    l.append(l[0])
    l.pop()
    b=b-1 
print(l)
```

it is showing the runtime error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 8, in 
    a = d % n
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Tip: try to `print(type(n), type(d))` right after your read them. What do you see? What would you expect those types to be?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 12, in <module>
    while(n>0):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: it is taking n as a string!

Comment: Yes, it is. James already provided an answer how to fix it ;)

Answer (score 2):

The result of `input()` is a string, which you split into two strings.  The line

```
a = d % n
```

is trying to using the older string formatting syntax which uses the percent symbol, because `d` is a string.  If you want to use `%` as the modulo operator, you need to convert `d` and `n` to numerics first.

```
n, d = input().split()
n, d = float(n), float(d)
```

Comment: Again it is showing error when I am taking input from the second line which contains values in the array.  The error is  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 13, in <module>
    k = input().split()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: What are you using for your inputs?

Answer (score 0):

```
n , d = input().split()
```

should be replaced with

```
n , d = input().split()
x, y = [int(x), int(y)]
```

the error is due to the fact that both x & y are strings and you need to convert them into integer